# how can I solve this character encoding issue with codeigniter-4

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, echo, codeigniter-4

I migrated my site to Codeigniter 4, and when I echo my database contents, some contents will show like this `â‡¾`, Please how can I get out of this?

this is my header content

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#490249">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <meta name="csrf-token">
```

Comment: What should be instead of that `â‡¾`? Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].